# Javascript redirect not working after returning from a post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using drag & drop to update a user avatar, I have almost got it finished bet very very stuck and need help.

Am not very experienced with java..  when a user drags/drops a new image it is getting written to database & uploaded properly.   All I want to do which I thought was pretty straight forward is to have the post window return via Json that an image has been uploaded, then refresh the page which would display the users new avatar.

```
  <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr class="template-upload{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    <td class="preview"></td>
    <td class="name">{{if name}}${name}{{else}}Untitled{{/if}}</td>
    <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
    {{if error}}
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><b>Error</b> :
            {{if error === 'maxFileSize'}}File too large! <br><small>(Files must be under 3Mb)</small>
            {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File too small! <br><small>(The file must be greater than 50Kb)</small>
            {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Invalid file type! <br><small>(Upload pictures only)</small>
            {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded
            {{else}}${error}
            {{/if}}
        </td>
    {{else}}
        <td class="progress"><div></div></td>
        <td class="start"><button>start</button></td>
    {{/if}}
    <td class="cancel"><button>cancel</button></td>
  </tr>
 </script>
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">       

<tr class="template-download{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    {{if error}}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name">${name}</td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><b>Error</b> :
            {{if error === 1}}File exceeds upload_max_filesize (php.ini directive)
            {{else error === 2}}File exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE (HTML form directive)
            {{else error === 3}}File was only partially uploaded
            {{else error === 4}}No File was uploaded
            {{else error === 5}}Missing a temporary folder
            {{else error === 6}}Failed to write file to disk
            {{else error === 7}}File upload stopped by extension
            {{else error === 'maxFileSize'}}File is too big
            {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File is too small
            {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Filetype not allowed
            {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded
            {{else error === 'uploadedBytes'}}Uploaded bytes exceed file size
            {{else error === 'emptyResult'}}Empty file upload result
            {{else}}unknown error has occured.<br><small>(Try again later)</small>
            {{/if}}

        </td>
    {{else}}        


<td class="preview">
            {{if thumbnail_url}}
            THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE REDIRECT TO BE SO THAT NEW AVATAR IS DISPLAYED
                <a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img src="${thumbnail_url}" width="80" height="80"></a>
            {{/if}}
  </td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="${url}"{{if thumbnail_url}} target="_blank"{{/if}}>${name}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {{/if}}
    <td class="delete">
        <button data-type="${delete_type}" data-url="${delete_url}">Sil</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: <td class="preview">
                {{if thumbnail_url}}
                {location.replace("http://www.mymusicwall.co.uk/index.asp");}                
                    <a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img src="${thumbnail_url}" width="80" height="80"></a>
                {{/if}}
            </td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="${url}"{{if thumbnail_url}} target="_blank"{{/if}}>${name}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {{/if}}

Comment: To allow this to happen, there must be a logged in person as the page avatar.asp is used as an iframe

Comment: The iframe avatar.asp is within the main page index.asp

Comment: does the syntax look ok?

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript redirection takes this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>
```

**Change this:**

```
    <td class="preview">
        {{if thumbnail_url}}
        {window.location("http://www.mymusicwall.co.uk/avatar.asp");}                
        {{/if}}
    </td>
```

**to this:**

```
    <td class="preview">
        {{if thumbnail_url}}
        {<script type="text/javascript">window.location("http://www.mymusicwall.co.uk/avatar.asp");</script>}                
        {{/if}}
    </td>
```

**Edit**

I'm not familiar with your templating system, but you need to put the redirect outside of the template. You can attach an event handler to whatever action it is that you want to redirect after, and then run the `window.location` as discussed above within that event handler. Be sure to check your console for errors, as I'm sure that's the majority of the reason why what you're trying isn't working.

Comment: Did you wrap it in `script` tags?

Comment: Also, If it works by itself, why not throw it into a function and call it from your original?

Comment: This is first time EVER that have asked for help as I have always worked out the solution.  So based on that, I really am stuck, have tried sooo many ways of doing this

Comment: Check your source. This JavaScript will work for redirection. Either you have a typo or your ASP conditionals are excluding it from the page.

Comment: {{if thumbnail_url}}
  {location.replace("http://www.mymusicwall.co.uk/index.asp");}   
              
                <a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img src="${thumbnail_url}" width="80"    height="80"></a>
            {{/if}}

Is this the correct syntax??

Comment: Where's your `script` tag? And it's `window.location`, not `location.replace`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15362/javascript-redirect-not-working-after-returning-from-a-post

Comment: I have updated the main question with the  starting & closing script tags.

Comment: Hi wanovak am still stuck with this :-(